# Javascript document.getElementById CSS not working?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Ive got a problem with hiding and showing a certain  tag. They are made to be a login and logout button for a login system im currently making. Logging in and logging out works perfect.

Hiding the login  tag works fine, and when logged out, it shows properly. However the same cannot be said with the logout  tag. When inspecting the actual page, i see its not getting any CSS changes as if its ignoring my javascript entirely.

So heres my HTML with Javascript function:

```
<div class="uitlog_inlog">
    <a href="login.php" class="navigatieknop_inlog" id="navigatieknop_inlog">Inloggen</a>
    <a href="loguit.php" class="navigatieknop_uitlog" id="navigatieknop_uitlog">Uitloggen</a>
    </div>
    <?php

        include 'login/inloggen.php';
        if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) ==true){
            $sessie = session_status();
            if($sessie == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
                session_start();
            } else {
            }
        }

        if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
            if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
            echo '<div class="welkom">Welkom ' .$_SESSION['login_user'] .'!</div>';
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        document.getElementById('navigatieknop_inlog').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('registratieknop').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('bewerken').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById('navigatieknop_uitlog').style.display = 'block';
                      </script>";

        } else {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        document.getElementById('navigatieknop_inlog').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById('registratieknop').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById('bewerken').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('navigatieknop_uitlog').style.display = 'none';
                      </script>";
        }
        }
    ?>
```

And heres my CSS:

```
        .navigatieknop_uitlog, .navigatieknop_inlog {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .navigatieknop:hover, .navigatieknop_end:hover, .navigatieknop_uitlog:hover, .navigatieknop_inlog:hover, .registratieknop:hover, .bewerkenknop:hover{
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 500ms linear;
    transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}
```

Comment: Javascript is working. Maybe the PHP echo is printing something wrong?

Comment: Not a PHP guy, so not sure but isn't PHP a scripting lang. So will this not run script before elements are rendered? Try creating a JS function and call it on `window.onload`

Comment: @Rajesh PHP DOES execute the script. The login "button" is in there aswell and that hides and shows prefectly fine. I even went as far as copy pasting the code from the working login button and change it to be for the logout button. Unfortunetly, somehow that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div class="uitlog_inlog">
  <a href="login.php" class="navigatieknop_inlog" id="navigatieknop_inlog">Inloggen</a>
  <a href="loguit.php" class="navigatieknop_uitlog" id="navigatieknop_uitlog">Uitloggen</a>
</div>
<?php

  include 'login/inloggen.php';
  if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) ==true){
    $sessie = session_status();
    if($sessie == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
      session_start();
    } else {
    }
  }

  if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      echo '<div class="welkom">Welkom ' .$_SESSION['login_user'] .'!</div>';
      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
              (function() {
              document.getElementById('navigatieknop_inlog').style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById('navigatieknop_uitlog').style.display = 'block';
              //document.getElementById('registratieknop').style.display = 'none';
              //document.getElementById('bewerken').style.display = 'block';
              })();
            </script>";
    } else {
      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                (function() {
                  document.getElementById('navigatieknop_inlog').style.display = 'block';
                  document.getElementById('navigatieknop_uitlog').style.display = 'none';
                  //document.getElementById('registratieknop').style.display = 'block';
                  //document.getElementById('bewerken').style.display = 'none';
                  })();
                </script>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: This works! Login button shows nicely when not logged in, and when logged in, the logout button shows! Thanks man! So all i had to do is put a function inside the script.

Comment: Phew! Had some issues posting the code. Can you please make sure that the edited code works too? Yes, so it is like it should do stuff only when the pages load, and the second possible problem was that few of the get element by id were failing.

Comment: Your edited code works fine aswell. What did you change to it?

Comment: Just commented few lines and indented it a little. :)

Comment: Ah yeah now i see it. Those buttons will have to work aswell, but commented those out temporarily so i could focus on the all important login/logout buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to style classes instead, or use JQuery

With JQuery you can do something like:

```
$('#navigatieknop_inlog').hide()
```

Or using classes

```
$('.navigatieknop_inlog').hide()
```

or using PHP

```
<div class="uitlog_inlog">

<?php
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
var_dump($_SESSION['loggedin']);
 if(!checkLoginStatus()){
?>
    <a href="login.php" class="navigatieknop_inlog" id="navigatieknop_inlog">Login</a>
 <?php  } 

elseif(checkLoginStatus()){  ?>
    <a href="loguit.php" class="navigatieknop_uitlog" id="navigatieknop_uitlog">Logout</a>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<?php

// include 'login/inloggen.php';

function checkLoginStatus(){
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === false) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}           

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) ==true){
    $sessie = session_status();
    if($sessie == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
        session_start();
    } else {
    }
}

if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    echo '<div class="welkom">Welkom ' .$_SESSION['login_user'] .'!</div>';
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                document.getElementById('navigatieknop_inlog').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('registratieknop').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('bewerken').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('navigatieknop_uitlog').style.display = 'block';
              </script>";

} else {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                document.getElementById('navigatieknop_inlog').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('registratieknop').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('bewerken').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('navigatieknop_uitlog').style.display = 'none';
              </script>";
}
}
```

?>

Comment: Please see the markup. OP is using same value as class and ID

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki User does not have enough rep to add comment

Comment: Yes i know but they should wait for the 50 rep since the system is designed that for a reason..

Comment: @Artan since this is more of a comment but your wish to help, please try to describe your idea instead of 1 line. That would help a bit more

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki instead of asking them not to answer, we should guide them how to frame a better answer. I tried in my previous comment. You can add if anything more is required. :-)

Comment: Using document.getElementByClassName doesnt work. Same results. In fact, when i try that on the working login <a> tag, it breaks it and doesnt hide it anymore.

Comment: @Artan JQuery didnt work. Did try your PHP code, and after adding a ";" after return false, the logout button didnt show when not logged in. However it doesnt show when logged in.